# Is it Possible to Preserve that Distinctive Smell of New PC Parts?

Tags: desktop-computer

I like the smell of new PC parts very much. Right now, I have been spending almost half an hour just enjoying the smell of some new PC parts I ordered a few days ago. I also did the same thing when I got my new laptop. I just love the smell so much that I can say I'm addicted.

So I'm thinking about doing something to preserve the smell, but have no idea how -- I'm not even sure if it's possible at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Interestingly enough, they do have this product for cars: [True New Car Air Freshener](http://www.amazon.com/SCENT-Freshener--SMELLS-BOUGHT-FOREVER/dp/B002J7VX4Y/ref=sr_1_1?s=automotive&ie=UTF8&qid=1329632990&sr=1-1). I could not find one for 'new computers', however.

Comment: If you tell me how to preserve the smell of new books...

Comment: @iglvzx Often "new car smell" is actually something like [3M Scotchgard](http://www.3m.com/product/information/Scotchgard-Fabric-Protector.html). :)  The smell of new computer parts is often the cleaning chemicals off-gassing, and is probably bad for you. :/

Comment: I can't find the link/study, but I am pretty sure I read something about studies saying this 'new computer' smell is highly carcinogenic.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could buy more PC parts. And once you have used up that new smell you could sell them on ebay.

Answer (score 2):

"Smell" is caused by chemicals in the air binding to olfactory receptors in the sinuses. The very act of smelling consumes these chemicals. There is no way to persist the smell other than to add more chemical, therefore "preserve smell" is a misnomer in and of itself.